# PsychoPy, threading and keyboard input

Tags: python-2.7, psychopy

We are building an experiment with **PyGaze** using **PsychoPy** to handle all the screen related stuff and the keyboard input. Since we are using multiple timers to trigger events, we try using threading in order to have the different tasks not blocked by each other. Therefore we are also planning to create an event handler for all the inputs including keyboard input and also input from an eye tracker and other hardware.

But if we try to run the event handler within its own thread, we can't get any keyboard input. Everything runs without any errors, but there is simply no keyboard input coming through to the **psychopy.event.getKeys() call**.

**PsychoPy** itself is initialised in the main tread since otherwise it causes problems with **OpenGL** and **pyglet**.

Is there any way to get this setup running or is it fundamentally not compatible with **PsychoPy**?

Comment: Just a very quick idea: have you tried using ``psychopy.iohub`` to get key events? It polls the keyboard in a separate thread and then pass it to the main psychopy thread when called. There's a iohub keyboard demo in PsychoPy Coder.

Comment: Ok, so now I tried `psychopy.iohub` and it kind of works. I get all the keyboard press and release events of keys which have a unicode representation and also all active modifier. But I would also like to use the keys without unicode representation like for example Escape. Is there a way to also get these keys?